# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-generator

I'm new on Node.js, and I try develop a simple movie api app with node.js and I created app with express-generator. I got this error and I couldn't handle it.

Firstly, I googled and I found github and stackoverflow I examined, but I couldn't resolve my issue.

firstly here error message :

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object
>       at validateString (internal/validators.js:112:11)
>       at extname (path.js:1231:5)
>       at new View (/Users/tugrul/Projects/Learning Projects/movie-api/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:56:14)
>       at Function.render (/Users/tugrul/Projects/Learning Projects/movie-api/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
>       at ServerResponse.render (/Users/tugrul/Projects/Learning Projects/movie-api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
>       at /Users/tugrul/Projects/Learning Projects/movie-api/app.js:45:7
>       at Layer.handle_error (/Users/tugrul/Projects/Learning Projects/movie-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
>       at trim_prefix (/Users/tugrul/Projects/Learning Projects/movie-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
>       at /Users/tugrul/Projects/Learning Projects/movie-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (/Users/tugrul/Projects/Learning Projects/movie-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>       at next (/Users/tugrul/Projects/Learning Projects/movie-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>       at /Users/tugrul/Projects/Learning Projects/movie-api/app.js:34:3
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/tugrul/Projects/Learning Projects/movie-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (/Users/tugrul/Projects/Learning Projects/movie-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
>       at /Users/tugrul/Projects/Learning Projects/movie-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (/Users/tugrul/Projects/Learning Projects/movie-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)

here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "movie-api",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.10",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1"
  }
}
```

and here is my app.js file:

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');

const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const movieRouter = require('./routes/movie');
const directorRouter = require('./routes/director');


const app = express();

//mongodb connection

const db = require('./helper/db')();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/api/movies', movieRouter);
app.use('api/directors', directorRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render({error:{message:err.message, code: err.code}});
});

module.exports = app;
```

and here is my director router file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
//Models

const Director = require('../models/Director');

    // Get All Movies
    router.get('/', (req, res, next) =>{
      res.json({message: 'Director APIs'});
    });


    module.exports = router;
```

And here is my movie router file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
//Models

const Movie = require('../models/Movie');

// Get All Movies
router.get('/', (req, res) =>{
  const promise = Movie.find({ });
  promise.then((data)=>{
    res.json(data);
  }).catch((err)=>{
    res.json(err)
  });
});

//Top 10 List
router.get('/top10', (req, res) =>{
  const promise = Movie.find({ }).limit(10).sort({ imdb_score: -1});
  promise.then((data)=>{
    res.json(data);
  }).catch((err)=>{
    res.json(err)
  });
});

//Add new movie
router.post('/add-movie',(req,res,next)=>{
  //const {title,imdb_score,category,country,year} = req.body;
  const movie = new Movie(req.body);

  const promise = movie.save();

  promise.then((data)=>{
    res.json(data);
  }).catch((err)=>{
    res.json(err);
  });

});


// Get Movie From ID
router.get('/:movie_id',(req,res,next)=>{
  const promise = Movie.findById((req.params.movie_id));
  promise.then((movie)=>{

    if(!movie){
      console.log(movie);
      next({message : 'This movie can not found!', code:404});
    }else{
      res.json(movie);
    }
  }).catch((err)=>{
    res.json(err);
  });

});


//Update Movie
router.put('/:movie_id',(req,res,next)=>{
  const promise = Movie.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.movie_id,
      req.body,
      {
        new: true
      });
  promise.then((movie)=>{

    if(!movie){
      console.log(movie);
      next({message : 'This movie can not found!', code:404});
    }else{
      res.json(movie);
    }
  }).catch((err)=>{
    res.json(err);
  });

});

//Delete movie
router.delete('/:movie_id',(req,res,next)=>{
  const promise = Movie.findByIdAndRemove(
      req.params.movie_id,
      req.body);
  promise.then((movie)=>{

    if(!movie){
      console.log(movie);
      next({message : 'This movie can not found!', code:404});
    }else{
      res.json({status: 1});
    }
  }).catch((err)=>{
    res.json(err);
  });

});

// get movies between two years
router.get('/between/:start_year/:end_year',(req,res,next)=>{
  const {start_year,end_year} = req.params;
  const promise = Movie.find(
      {
        // gte = ">=", lte = "<="
        year: { "$gte": parseInt(start_year), "$lte": parseInt(end_year)}
      }
  );
  promise.then((movie)=>{

    if(!movie){
      console.log(movie);
      next({message : 'This movie can not found!', code:404});
    }else{
      res.json(movie);
    }
  }).catch((err)=>{
    res.json(err);
  });

});


module.exports = router;
```

When I try to access http://localhost:3000/api/directors I get this error. Why? How can I handle it?

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following line:

```
res.render({error:{message:err.message, code: err.code}});
```

According to the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render), `render` expects the first parameter to be a path to the html-page to be rendered. Assuming there's a file called `error` in your views directory, changing it to

```
res.render('error', {error:{message:err.message, code: err.code}});
```

should fix the problem.

Regarding the second question from the comments:

The problem here is your middleware:

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  next(createError(404));
});
```

Basically every request will result in an error, as you set up an ordinary middleware which will also be executed on a successful request. So you can probably just remove this middleware, as you have error handlers set up anyway.

Comment: It worked. Now 404 not foun I got. Thanks! Let me ask you one more thing. On my code everthing seems well but I couldn't reach my rest api, 404 not found I get. Do you think where is a mistake?